# Angular viewportScroller not working. Scrolltop never changes. Can only move to anchor by changing url

Tags: angular, scroll, anchor

I am trying to use anchors as a way of scrolling through my guided setup using Angular's ViewportScroller.

In my step-three-funds component, I have a div with a template variable reference and ID that I'm trying to scroll to (With an offset later, if I can get this working).

`<div #section2 id="section2" class="interest-income-section">`

I've imported the Viewport Scroller, named it in my constructor, and make calls in several places to scroll to my anchor:

`import { ViewportScroller } from '@angular/common'`

`constructor(private store: Store, private router: Router, private viewportScroller: ViewportScroller) {}`

`this.viewportScroller.scrollToAnchor('section2')`

None of which work. I've found that if I append "#section2" to my url and hit enter, it will move to the anchored section, but only one time. As a side note, I have tried using anchors from Angular Router. This does succeed in changing my url, but will not scroll to my desired anchor point, even with anchorScrolling: "enabled" in my routingModule. (I would prefer to use viewportScroller anyways).

I've also noticed that if I dive into the document/component objects or listen to scroll events, my scroll position "scrollTop" never changes. It always stays the same number, and I'm curious if that has anything to do with my issue.

Also, my scrollbar is set on the  tag of an imported main navigational component, but the routed page that I'm on is step-three-funds. I'm also curious if this has anything to do with my predicament. I've attached a screenshot of the document hierarchy below.

[image]

Comment: Try to wrap app-step-three-funds component inside anchor tag and check

Comment: That doesn't do anything, but I don't think it would. The only thing on this page is the topbar from my primary nav, a top banner, and the step-three-funds that takes up the rest of the page.

Comment: Not sure why it's not working for you. I have tried in stackblitz it's working fine see:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dkyc1r?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: I think it may have to do with that fact that the element being scrolled is the <section class="contentFullWidth"> and the page that we are on is step-three-funds

Comment: Same issue. It just wouldn't work. This did however     document.getElementById("banner").scrollIntoView({
      behavior: "smooth"
    });   ...where banner is the id of the DOM element to scroll to